# Grouped barplot with two factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, tibble

I would like to create a boxplot with ggplot2 which has a factor variable on the x-axis, a numeric value on the y-axis and multiple bars per each x-axis tick.
This is a tibble similar to the one that I'm using:

```
A tibble: 26 x 4
     Param Value      Res                   Comp
    <fctr> <dbl>   <fctr>                  <chr>
 1    Par1 13.45      Re1                      a
 2    Par2 10.86      Re1                      a
 3    Par3 10.32      Re2                      a
 4    Par2 23.62      Re2                      a
 5    Par1 19.43      Re2                      a
 6    <NA>  0.00      Re3                      b
 7    <NA>  0.00      Re4                      b
 8    Par1 27.44      Re5                      b
 9    <NA>  0.00      Re6                      b
10    <NA>  0.00      Re6                      b
```

Here's the data:

```
structure(list(Param = c("Par1", "Par2", "Par3", "Par1", 
"Par4", NA, NA, "Par5", NA, NA, "Par6", "Par3", "Par7", "Par8", 
"Par3", "Par3", "Par6", "Par3", "Par7", "Par8", "Par3", "Par3", 
"Par6", "Par3", "Par7", "Par8"), Value = c(13.45, 10.86, 10.32, 
23.62, 19.43, 0, 0, 27.44, 0, 0, 11.37, 37.94, 11.23, 22.8, 19.25, 
22.26, 11.36, 19.03, 11.94, 22.79, 14.22, 17.21, 11.66, 23.93, 
12.33, 23.39), Res = c("Re1", "Re1", "Re2", "Re2", "Re2", 
"Re3", "Re4", "Re5", "Re6", "Re6_DOC", "Re7", "Re7", "Re7", 
"Re7", "Re6", "Re6_1", "Re7", "Re7", "Re7", "Re7", "Re6", 
"Re6_1", "Re7", "Re7", "Re7", "Re7"), Comp = c("Comp1", 
"Comp1", "Comp1", "Comp1", 
"Comp1", "Comp1", "Comp1", 
"Comp1", "Comp2", "Comp2", "Comp2", 
"Comp2", "Comp2", "Comp2", "Comp3", 
"Comp3", "Comp3", "Comp3", "Comp3", "Comp3", 
"Comp4", "Comp4", "Comp4", "Comp4", "Comp4", 
"Comp4")), .Names = c("Param", "Value", "Res", "Comp"), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -26L))
```

So I'd like to have Res on the x-axis, Value on the y-axis and, in case multiple Params are present for each Res there should be different columns. I want also that in the facet wrap, if a Res is not present it should not be on the x-axis (for example Re1 should not be in the b facet).

For now I've done this:

```
tibble %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=Res,y=Value)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge",stat = "identity") +
  facet_wrap(~Comp)
```

But a single bar appears for every Res and on the x-axis of the various facets empty ticks appear.
Does anyone know how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: look at the scales argument to facet_wrap

Comment: Ok, thanks. That solves the scale problem. Do you know about solving the issue with the groups?

Comment: I have found that if i add in aes "fill=Param" I do get the different bars, but now I'd like them to be all of the same width and have Param as a label on top of each

Comment: labels will need geom_text() or geom_label(). To fix the widths, look at position_dodge2()

Answer (score 1):

The code for the final image is then:

```
df%>%ggplot(aes(x=Res,y=Value,fill=Param,label=Param))+geom_bar(position=position_dodge2(width = 0.9, preserve = "single"),stat = "identity")+facet_wrap(~Comp,scales = "free_x", as.table = FALSE)+
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(width = 0.9),hjust="top",angle = 90,size=5) + guides(fill=FALSE)+scale_fill_manual(values=brewer.pal(8, "Paired"))+theme(axis.title.x=element_blank())+scale_y_continuous("Percentage")
```